# Conditional Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be events with $A_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$. Show that 
>   $$\biggl\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{P}[A_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=\infty\biggr\} = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n \text{ a. s.}$$
>
> *Hint:* Consider the martingale $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \bigl(1_{A_i} - \mathbf{P}[A_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\bigr)$.

I don't even know how to start with this exercise. I think one has to use the result that martingales with bounded increments either converge or diverge to $\pm \infty$ almost surely.

Can you give me a hint? Thanks for your time.

Comment: [Full proof](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yAMtOS6G4sgC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22Conditional+Borel-Cantelli+lemma%22&source=bl&ots=nX84gdyzTD&sig=b0MDfmmtv20axH5yaF8vfQJMmb8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Kz0gVeKSEcL1arSHgoAI&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22Conditional%20Borel-Cantelli%20lemma%22&f=false).